# hibernate join fetch dump result

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to the hibernate.  Can some one explain why the first query gets the dump results? thanks!

shop entity

```
....
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop")
private Collection<Product> productCollection;
....
```

product entity

```
....
 @JoinColumn(name = "shopId", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne
private Shop shop;
....
```

query1 result

```
from Shop s left join fetch s.productCollection

shop1 : product1 product2 product3 product4 product5 product6 product7 product8 product9 product10 product11 
shop1 : product1 product2 product3 product4 product5 product6 product7 product8 product9 product10 product11 
shop1 : product1 product2 product3 product4 product5 product6 product7 product8 product9 product10 product11 
shop1 : product1 product2 product3 product4 product5 product6 product7 product8 product9 product10 product11 
shop1 : product1 product2 product3 product4 product5 product6 product7 product8 product9 product10 product11 
shop1 : product1 product2 product3 product4 product5 product6 product7 product8 product9 product10 product11 
shop1 : product1 product2 product3 product4 product5 product6 product7 product8 product9 product10 product11 
shop1 : product1 product2 product3 product4 product5 product6 product7 product8 product9 product10 product11 
shop1 : product1 product2 product3 product4 product5 product6 product7 product8 product9 product10 product11 
shop1 : product1 product2 product3 product4 product5 product6 product7 product8 product9 product10 product11 
shop1 : product1 product2 product3 product4 product5 product6 product7 product8 product9 product10 product11 
shop2 : product12
```

query2 result

```
from Product p right join fetch p.shop

 product1 : shop1
product2 : shop1
product3 : shop1
product4 : shop1
product5 : shop1
product6 : shop1
product7 : shop1
product8 : shop1
product9 : shop1
product10 : shop1
product11 : shop1
product12 : shop2
```

ps. if you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Use natural join instead of left outer join. This is happening because you have shop1 in multiple products. For every product it will try to join with shop1.

**Edit 1:** Another **JPA** provider(**hibernate**) specific solution is using `private Set<Product> productCollection;` instead of `private Collection<Product> productCollection;` That will fetch unique result.

Hope it works.

Comment: but I am using the hsql, not the native sql

Comment: show me your code so that i can understand. Specially, entity and dao and service class.